# How to display text content from sqlite based on adjusting font size dynamically in android

Tags: android, sqlite

I have `Sqlite` textual data which  I want to display on `layout vertically` side by side like a book. Each row of `Sqlite` data is same as each line in `layout`. When font size is increased or decreased the line should be adjusted to the next line in the `layout`.
Thanks in advance

Comment: do provide a wireframe of your expectation or code which you where able to write so that you get quick help

Comment: I have created Two LinearLayout say linear1 and linear2. In each linearlayouts I have shown textual lines using texviews. My problem is at bottom of linear1. If Textview can't show complete text retrieved from Sqlite, For example Sqlite data has 3 lines of text to display, but bottom textviews shows only 2 lines, in that case the entire 3 lines of text should be shifted to linear2 to show complete text. And population of text data continues. This action should be applied for font increase or decrease also. How to do that??